# regular expression that matches a string where the string DOESNT lead with 'username'

Tags: regex

So I'm trying to write a regex and get it to match the string ONLY if the string doesn't start with the string 'username'

I tried something like ^([^username])... but that matches strings where the string doesn't start with any of those letters.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `if(str.indexOf("username") != 0)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
^(?!username)
```

using a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

The other option, depending on what your doing, would be to simply invert your logic. For instance, if you were doing

```
if foo matches <regex>
```

then just do

```
if !(foo matches <regex>)
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you're using Perl: you can use the negative binding operator:

```
if($text !~ /^username/) {
    # do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> but that matches strings where the
>   string doesn't start with any of those
>   letters.

That's because square brackets (`[]`) denote a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and the caret (`^`) negates the character class.

That being said, why do you *have* to use regex? This can be done with simple string matching, which is generally faster than regex. If there is a match check and see if the position is not the beginning of the string. You didn't specify a language, but most of them support this.